# How to change the outerstride in Eigen matrices without using map function

Tags: matrix, eigen

I want to change the outerstride of Eigen matrix at compile time without using map function.

I tried to change this using OuterStrideAtCompileTime variable,but it doesn't work.Is there any way to do that ?

One more thing printing mat.Outerstride() every time gives number of rows of input matrix.How to print OuterStride of eigen matrix?

Thanks in advance.

---

I was defining an eigen matrix with map function like

```
MatrixXf mat;
float arr[16] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
mat =  Map<Matrix<float,Dynamic,Dynamic,Eigen::RowMajor>, 0, OuterStride<Dynamic> > (arr,4,4,OuterStride<Dynamic>(5));
```

It's working fine, whenever I tried to change the outer stride by using

```
mat.OuterStrideAtCompileTime = 7;
```

It's not working.

Comment: Why do you want to change it? Can you show some code on how you change it?

Comment: I want to work with matrices of different strides.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I cannot imagine any there's a common matrix operation that need to change it.

Comment: Why not use a map? That's exactly what it's for. They don't have to copy the data...

Answer (score 0):

Outer stride is a parameter related to the data storage. A more commonly used name is leading dimension. You could find some explaination here.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFHY8_5.3.0/com.ibm.cluster.essl.v5r3.essl100.doc/am5gr_leaddi.htm

Basically for an existing matrix, it can not be changed. The only way to change it without changing the elements of the matrix is to copy the matrix to a new memory space using a different outer stride setting. This usually happens when you copy a matrix into another as a sub-matrix.

For a column major matrix the minimum possible outer stride equals to the number of rows, as the number you have printed out.

When using Eigen, you don't need worry about it as Eigen usually takes care of it for you expect for `Eigen::Map`.

---

You code actually doesn't work. Setting out stride to 5 is already out of range as the existing matrix(4x4) stored in `arr` is of stride 4 and `stride 5 x 4 columns = 20 > 16`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

int main(void) {
  using namespace Eigen;
  MatrixXf mat;
  float arr[16] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };

  mat = Map<Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>, 0,
      OuterStride<Dynamic> >(arr, 4, 4, OuterStride<Dynamic>(5));
  std::cout << "mat with stride 5:\n" << mat << std::endl;

  mat = Map<Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>, 0,
      OuterStride<Dynamic> >(arr, 4, 4, OuterStride<Dynamic>(4));
  std::cout << "mat with stride 4:\n" << mat << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Please compare the output.

```
mat with stride 5:
          1           2           3           4
          6           7           8           9
         11          12          13          14
         16           0           0 5.01639e-14
mat with stride 4:
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

If you extend the array to 20 elements

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

int main(void) {
  using namespace Eigen;
  MatrixXf mat;
  float arr[20] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };

  Map<Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>, 0, OuterStride<Dynamic> > map1(arr, 4, 4, OuterStride<Dynamic>(5));
  mat = map1;
  std::cout << "map1 outer stride: " << map1.outerStride() << std::endl << map1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "mat outer stride: " << mat.outerStride() << std::endl << mat << std::endl;

  Map<Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>, 0, OuterStride<Dynamic> > map2(arr, 4, 4, OuterStride<Dynamic>(4));
  mat = map2;
  std::cout << "map2 outer stride: " << map2.outerStride() << std::endl << map2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "mat outer stride: " << mat.outerStride() << std::endl << mat << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
map1 outer stride: 5
 1  2  3  4
 6  7  8  9
11 12 13 14
16 17 18 19
mat outer stride: 4
 1  2  3  4
 6  7  8  9
11 12 13 14
16 17 18 19
map2 outer stride: 4
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
mat outer stride: 4
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

You could also see the outer stride changes when copying `map1` to `mat`.
Hope this give you a better view of what out stride is.

In fact in your original code, you are using `Map` in a wrong way - you shouldn't have copied `Map()` to `Matrix mat`.
That's why when you print the stride of `mat`, it is always 4.
What you need to do is to eliminate the unnecessary data copy and print the stride of `map1`/`map2`.

Comment: How to print the outerstride of an matrix?

Comment: @Madhu as in your question `mat.outerStride();`

Comment: printing mat.outerStride() every time gives number of rows of input matrix,irrespective of the storage order.

Comment: @Madhu if you show a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code that reproduce your problem, it will be easier. See my updated code and you will know why.

Comment: I want the outerstride of mat1,for creating destination matrix with same outerstride as mat1.Is there any function to print using mat1.

Comment: Why do you want that, if `mat1` and `mat` represent the same matrix with the only difference of stride? That's only a waste of padding space.

Comment: If strides are different,then automatically the data of matrices are also different.

Comment: In my second output, the first two matrices `map1` and `mat`, they have different stride but same data.